# If I have a function from $\mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^n$, is a directional derivative a vector or a scalar?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

This is the definition given:

Let $A \subset \mathbb{R}^m$; let $f: A \to \mathbb{R}^n$. Suppose $A$ contains a neighborhood of $\vec{a}$. Given $\vec{u} \in \mathbb{R}^m$, with $\vec{u} \neq 0$, define:

$$f'(\vec{a}, \vec{u}) = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{f(\vec{a}+t\vec{u})-f(\vec{a})}{t} $$

Since the function maps into $\mathbb{R}^n$, this limit should be contained in $\mathbb{R}^n$ (and thus, be a vector), but all the googling I've done have led me to posts saying that the directional derivative is a scalar and not a vector.

Comment: As you say, it is obviously a vector.

Comment: for $f:R^m \to R$ directional derivative is scalar .

Comment: Are partial derivatives only defined for functions $f:R^m \to R$ ?

Comment: The directional derivative of a scalar function takes scalar values. Presumably that is what the "posts" from your googling are saying. You do not link to any of  these posts.

Comment: If anything, the word "directional" should be a big clue as to what it is. . .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the definition you can prove that $f'(\vec a, \vec u)$ is a linear operatore that for any vector $\vec u \in \mathbb{R}^m$ gives a vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$.  So the directional derivative is a **linear operator** whose value is a vector or a scalar, depending on what is $n$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ .